# Поясните пожалуйста почему не работает.)

Tags: python

```
    defaults_commands = {
    'help': print('text')
}

print(Headband)

work = True
while work == True:
    defaults_commands(input('\n >>> '))
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Как это должно работать, по-вашему?

Comment: ввожу help, а в ответ получаю text

Comment: @nettle. В вашем варианте print выполняется сразу. Чтобы он выполнился потом вам нужно получить из словаря ссылку на функцию и потом её вызвать.

Answer (score 2):

```
defaults_commands = {
    'help': lambda: print('text')
}

work = True
while work:
    val = input('\n >>> ')
    if val not in defaults_commands:
        print(f'Unknown command "{val}"!')
        continue

    defaults_commands[val]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает:

```
def p():
  print('text')

defaults_commands = {
'help': p
}

#print(Headband)

work = True
while work == True:
    defaults_commands[input('\n >>> ')]()
```

Comment: Кстати, вместо отдельной функции можно было использовать `lambda: print('text')`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Я пробовал лямбду, но недоразобрался :)

Comment: `'help': lambda: print('text')`

Comment: Да теперь то понял

Comment: ```
defaults_commands = {
 'help': lambda: print('text')
} 
```

Invlalid syntax

Comment: @nettle. Странно, я проверял - работает. Python то 3-й? А то я не помню есть ли labmda во 2-м.